# Parsing nginx error log through fluentd

Tags: nginx, error-log

I am looking to parse nginx error log file and put the parsed format to elasticsearch. I was able to do same with access.log as it accepts log_format directive, but error.log doesn't. I have following sample error logs that I am mainly interested in :

```
2018/01/10 06:26:31 [error] 13485#13485: *64285471 limiting connections by zone "rl_conn", client: xx.xx.xx.xx, server: www.xyz.com, request: "GET /api/xyz HTTP/1.1", host: "www.xyz.com"
```

I want to parse this up through some parser, so that I get json format like :

```
{client: "xx.xx.xx.xx", server: "www.xyz.com", host: "www.xyz.com", "request": "GET /api/xyz HTTP/1.1", reason: "limiting connections by zone "rl_conn""}
```

Can anyone help here?

Comment: Have you found a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

@serut has a pretty good solution at the bottom of this Github issue: https://github.com/fluent/fluentd/issues/2991

```
# Use NGINX parse for front logs
<label @PARSENGINX>
    <filter front>
        @type parser
        key_name message
        <parse>
            @type nginx
        </parse>
    </filter>
    <filter front>
        # Handle errors
        @type parser
        key_name message
        <parse>
            @type regexp
            expression /^(?<logtime>\d{4}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}) (?<log_level>\[[^\s]+\]) (?<message>.*)$/
            time_key logtime
            time_format %Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S
        </parse>
    </filter>
    <match **>
        @type copy
        <store>
            @type relabel
            @label @OUTPUT
        </store>
    </match>
</label>
```